# What is correct way to set InputProps in DateRangePicker

Tags: material-ui

I have this DateRangePicker:

```
   <DateRangePicker
      InputProps={{???}}
      renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
        <>
          <TextField {...startProps} helperText="" size="small" placeholder="" />
          <DateRangeDelimiter>to</DateRangeDelimiter>
          <TextField {...endProps} helperText="" size="small" placeholder="" />
        </>
      )}
    />
```

you can see that props are duplicated in all TextFields `helperText="" size="small" placeholder=""`

is it possible to provide all InputProps from the parent `<DateRangePicker>` not to duplicate props in all childs?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation:

> Any prop not recognized by the pickers and their sub-components are passed down to material-ui TextField component.

This basically means that you can set all 3 properties on the `DateRangePicker` itself:

```
<DateRangePicker
    helperText=""
    size="small"
    placeholder="" 
    ...
/>
```

Comment: Can you please create a working example? (using https://codesandbox.io for example).